# Integrity constraint violation after adding new field to entity class

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony4

I am working on Symfony 4 project. I want to add a new field to my Wallpaper entity class. After adding it:

```
   /**
    * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
    */
    private $file;
```

I ran: `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:diff`

This is the migration file it generates:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace DoctrineMigrations;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema;
use Doctrine\Migrations\AbstractMigration;

/**
 * Auto-generated Migration: Please modify to your needs!
 */
final class Version20181019082359 extends AbstractMigration
{
    public function up(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this up() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'sqlite', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'sqlite\'.');

        $this->addSql('DROP INDEX IDX_D592642C12469DE2');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __temp__wallpaper AS SELECT id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height FROM wallpaper');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE wallpaper');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE wallpaper (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, category_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, filename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE BINARY, slug VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL COLLATE BINARY, width INTEGER NOT NULL, height INTEGER NOT NULL, file VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT FK_D592642C12469DE2 FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES category (id) NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE)');
        $this->addSql('INSERT INTO wallpaper (id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height) SELECT id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height FROM __temp__wallpaper');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE __temp__wallpaper');
        $this->addSql('CREATE INDEX IDX_D592642C12469DE2 ON wallpaper (category_id)');
    }

    public function down(Schema $schema) : void
    {
        // this down() migration is auto-generated, please modify it to your needs
        $this->abortIf($this->connection->getDatabasePlatform()->getName() !== 'sqlite', 'Migration can only be executed safely on \'sqlite\'.');

        $this->addSql('DROP INDEX IDX_D592642C12469DE2');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE __temp__wallpaper AS SELECT id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height FROM wallpaper');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE wallpaper');
        $this->addSql('CREATE TABLE wallpaper (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, category_id INTEGER DEFAULT NULL, filename VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, slug VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL, width INTEGER NOT NULL, height INTEGER NOT NULL)');
        $this->addSql('INSERT INTO wallpaper (id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height) SELECT id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height FROM __temp__wallpaper');
        $this->addSql('DROP TABLE __temp__wallpaper');
        $this->addSql('CREATE INDEX IDX_D592642C12469DE2 ON wallpaper (category_id)');
    }
}
```

After: `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

I get an error:

```
Migration 20181019082359 failed during Execution. Error An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO wallpaper (id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height) SELECT id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height FROM __temp__wallpaper':

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: wallpaper.file

In AbstractSQLiteDriver.php line 59:

  An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO wallpaper (id, category_id, filename, slug, width, height) SELECT id, category_id, filename, slug, w  
  idth, height FROM __temp__wallpaper':                                                                                                                    

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: wallpaper.file                                                           


In PDOConnection.php line 109:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: wallpaper.file  


In PDOConnection.php line 107:

  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: wallpaper.file
```

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: `NOT NULL constraint failed` you probably need to set a default value or allow the column to be null (in the DB schema).  Because it's new there is no data in that column.  I'm old school so I would just run an `ALTER TABLE wallpaper ALTER COLUMN file VARCHAR(255) NULL`

Comment: I guess you could use those fany annotation things `@ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)` If I remember my doctrine.  I got pretty upset with it a few years ago when I was dealing with 100 million rows, and gave up on it.

Comment: I did that. Then I get this error: General error: 1 no such index: IDX_D592642C12469DE2 .... I ran php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force .... that fix the issue.

Comment: `that fix the issue` - Kool  ;-/